# Cannot read property of undefined in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I am getting Cannot read property  of undefined in angular 6 but its value is displaying in template.here is my code

```
  this.data.post_data('dashboard/gettodaydata','',true)
               .subscribe((data:any) => {
                 this.today_datas =data.data;
              });
```

and this is my template file

```
<span class="counter text-danger">{{ today_datas.total_cpc | number }}</span>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Binding is trying to get evaluate before `today_datas` gets populated from API call. Use `navigation`/`elvis` operator

```
{{ today_datas?.total_cpc | number }}
```